# Is it possible to loop this syntax

Tags: syntax, macros, statistics, spss

I have been trying for some time to loop the following sytanx say 10 times.

```
COMPUTE tempvar=UNIFORM(10).
SORT CASES BY behaviour_code tempvar (A).
SPLIT FILE BY behaviour_code.
COMPUTE tempvar=1.
CREATE filter=CSUM(tempvar).
RECODE filter (1 thru 100=1) (3 thru highest=0).
SPLIT FILE OFF.

DISCRIMINANT
/GROUPS=behaviour_code(1 4)
/VARIABLES=hx hy hz
/SELECT=filter(1)
/ANALYSIS ALL
/PRIORS EQUAL
/STATISTICS=TABLE CROSSVALID
/CLASSIFY=NONMISSING POOLED.
EXECUTE.
```

The syntax itself randomly selects x number of cases from each group and and then runs DISCRIMINANT command.

I have tried the following using the loop command:

```
SET MXLOOPS=10.
LOOP. 
COMPUTE tempvar=UNIFORM(10).
SORT CASES BY behaviour_code tempvar (A).
SPLIT FILE BY behaviour_code.
COMPUTE tempvar=1.
CREATE filter=CSUM(tempvar).
RECODE filter (1 thru 100=1) (3 thru highest=0).
SPLIT FILE OFF.

DISCRIMINANT
/GROUPS=behaviour_code(1 4)
/VARIABLES=hx hy hz
/SELECT=filter(1)
/ANALYSIS ALL
/PRIORS EQUAL
/STATISTICS=TABLE CROSSVALID
/CLASSIFY=NONMISSING POOLED.
EXECUTE.
END LOOP.
```

Could anyone please advise on how to best get the original script to effectively resample a given number of times please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put procedures inside loops.  You can loop anything, however, using Python programmability if you install the Python Essentials from the SPSS Community website.